# Text not centered with justify-content: center

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got a div with `display: flex`. Its content is centered horizontally and vertically.

When content is too long in the div, the content wraps. But the alignment is broken in this case. See the snippet.

If I add `text-align: center` it displays correctly. But why doesn't it center without `text-align: center`?

```css
.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 10px;
}

.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.with-align{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box flex">
  some long text here
</div>

<div class="box flex with-align">
  some long text here
</div>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The HTML structure of a flex container has three levels:

- the container
- the item
- the content

Each level represents a separate, independent element.

The `justify-content` property, which is set on flex containers, controls flex items. It has no direct control over the children of the item (the text, in this case).

When you set `justify-content: center` on a row-direction container the item shrinks to the content width (i.e., shrink-to-fit) and is horizontally centered. The content, being inside the item, goes along for the ride.

Everything is centered nicely, *when the content is narrower than the flex container*.

On the other hand, *when the content is wider than the flex container*, the flex item can no longer be centered. In fact, the item cannot be aligned at all (`start`, `end`, `center`) because there is no free space – the item is consuming the full width of the container.

In such cases, the text can wrap. But `justify-content: center` doesn't apply to the text. It never did. The text was always subject to the default [**`text-align: start`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) (`left` in LTR / `right` in RTL).

Therefore, to center the text directly, add `text-align: center` to the flex item (or the flex container, it doesn't really matter due to [inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance)).

```css
article {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

/* demo styles only */
article {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;  
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p>some long text here</p>
</article>

<article>
  <p class="center">some long text here</p>
</article>
```