# Center text with images in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, center

I'm making a webpage and need to center-align 3 divs as promo content, like that:

[image]

In order to get this spacing and alignment, I added invisible images and made then hidden on mobile, so they get responsive, like that:

```
<div id="promocontent">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="img/iconenope.png">
  <img class="img-responsive hidden hide-on-med-and-down" src="img/iconehidden.png">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="img/iconenope.png">
  <img class="img-responsive hidden hide-on-med-and-down" src="img/iconehidden.png">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="img/iconenope.png"><br><br>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#promocontent {
display: flex;                  /* establish flex container */
flex-direction: row;            /* default value; can be omitted */
flex-wrap: nowrap;              /* default value; can be omitted */
justify-content: space-between; /* switched from default (flex-start, see below) */
padding: 5px;
}
```

Now, I need to add text on the center-bottom of these images, something like:

[image]

So, how can I do that (responsively working)? Align 2 lines of text (maybe 1, but 2 would be better).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using an extra image for spacing and just rely on `justify-content: space-between`

Feel free to check out my codepen (basically the same as Michaels).

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKmaVJ

Comment: Are there any advantages? Like what's wrong with my extra img?

Comment: Nothing, except you're forcing the user to download unnecessary weight. We want as little as possible -- that's design perfection. You can also try ```space-around``` to experiment with the spacing.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#promocontent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px;
}
#promocontent > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;       /* horizontally center child elements */
  text-align: center;        /* horizontally center text on narrow screens;
                                see http://stackoverflow.com/q/39678610/3597276 */
}
```

```html
<div id="promocontent">
  <div>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
    <h2>header text</h2>
    <span>text text text text text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
    <h2>header text</h2>
    <span>text text text text text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
    <h2>header text</h2>
    <span>text text text text text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x2rzj1cu/2/

Comment: Can you post more info or a demo of how you want it to be?

Comment: Your second image looks just like my demo. Where is the difference?

Comment: (sorry 2 comments) I want to achieve the second image, I don't hve it

Comment: Well, you can see it works in the demo. Maybe post the code from your real page.

Comment: I've made a fiddle, and yeah, it works. Somewhy, it does not in my page. i'll post the full page code...

Comment: You're complaining about my code, yet the answer you accepted is based entirely on my answer. He even states that in his answer.

Comment: If you look at my code, you'll notice it's pure flexbox which, *by definition*, is fully responsive. (The images I included were solely for demo purposes because you didn't include any.)

Comment: Anyway, I'm glad you found your solution. Take care and good luck.