# Why wouldn't text-align align text in a div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Aligning a text in a `div` is done via `text-align`. It normally works fine:

```html
<div style="text-align:right;border:1px solid red">
  this goes to the right
</div>
```

I have a piece of code (in the middle of a large HTML generated with the help of vue.js) where the alignment is not applied. I forced a width of a `div` and wanted the text inside it to be aligned to the right:

[image]

There is ample space for the `8:00`to move to the right but it stays centered. The CSS stack does not show anything special for this element:

[image]

**What could be the reason for this alignment (or lack of)?**

Note: I am not including the whole HTML/SCSS code as there is quite a lot of it - hopefully the CSS stack is enough?

Comment: please add your code instead of adding images

Comment: @DreamHunter: not sure if you have seen my note at the very bottom of the question (which I put, anticipating such -rightful- requests). I always put a minimal code to reproduce the issue - here (as you can imagine from the multiple `.scss` files), the place where the issue happens is buried in a ton of generated HTML.

Comment: possible duplicate: [*Why do I need “text-align: center” when the container has “justify-content: center”?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39678610/3597276)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex items shrink to fit the content width or height if the flex container's relevant value isn't set to `stretch` and flex item's `flex-grow` isn't set to `1`. Which means the size of the box is the size of the content, so that `text-align` has no effects. (Of course, there are also `flex-basis` and `width` factors, won't discuss here.)

Also note that text that is directly contained inside a flex container is automatically wrapped in an anonymous flex item.

You can fix that by setting this on the flex container:

```
div.start_display {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Or, reset it to the default block if you don't need flex there:

```
div.start_display {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Or, wrap it into another tag, let's say a `<span>`:

```
div.start_display span {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}
```

You may need to increase the specificity level on the selector, as it's unclear on the screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using `display: flex` here, `text-align` won't work. Change

```
div {
 justify-content: space-around;
}
```

to

```
div {
 justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Edit: as @Jacob Gray notice, adding `display: flex` on `div` element isn't a good idea. It would be better to remove this property from `div` and use `text-align` where you need it

Comment: I think the issue here is more that the OP is displaying every `div` on the page flex.

Comment: Right! This definitely is a problem! :)

Comment: @JacobGray: the whole page is entirely made up of "bricks" (several layers deep) which all stay together via `flex`. This was my reason to have  `flex` as the default display.

Comment: @WoJ I would still recommend having a more specific selector.