# Why does a flex column child not span 100% width when margin 0 auto given?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This occurred when using Zurb Foundation's XY grid but actually is a vanilla CSS Flex question; consider the following code:

```
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:100vh">
  <div style="flex: 1;background-color:yellow">

  </div>

  <div style="
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    padding-right: 0.9375rem;
    padding-left: 0.9375rem;

    margin: 0 auto;
    ">
  Why does this not span 100% width<br/>like any block elem would?
  </div>
</div>
```

([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqd2er5z/5/))

Why does the bottom div in its X-axis only takes as much width as needed by its content instead of taking the full width like any block element would normally do; and what should I do in order to achieve this (something better than settings its width to 100% maybe?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `margin 0 auto` you are using a shorthand property to say this:

- `margin-top: 0`
- `margin-right: auto`
- `margin-bottom: 0`
- `margin-left: auto`

In flexbox, `auto` margins consume all space in their defined direction. So `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` will consume all available space on either side of the flex item, therefore centering the item.

If you simply want to center the text, then instead of `auto` margins on the flex item, center the actual text:

Instead of this:

```
div { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Try this:

```
div { display: flex; justify-content: center; text-align: center; }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:100vh">
  <div style="flex: 1;background-color:yellow">
  </div>
  <div style="
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    padding-right: 0.9375rem;
    padding-left: 0.9375rem;
    
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    ">
    Why does this not span 100% width<br/>like any block elem would?
  </div>
</div>
```

More details:

- [Methods for Aligning Flex Items along the Main Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
- [Text not centered with justify-content: center](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39678610/3597276)

Comment: I can't see the value of adding `display: flex; justify-content: center;`, `text-align: center` is enough, right?

Comment: Hi @LGSon, yes, that is likely true. Using flex properties may be useful in the event the OP wants vertical centering, as well.

Comment: Hi ... right, and I was about to add, _unless they add a child element that  of  course_.