# Can align text to center at flex display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

What my problem is, that i cant align the text to center horizontally. Vertically, i aligned it the center, but horizontally, i cant. 
(When the text is longer, its centered horizontally?! If i see it right.)

I tryed adding the `<a>` element `display:block` and `text-align:center`, but it didnt solved my problem.

I attach a photo of the site.[Photo-Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL35j.png)

The `<a>` element is in a `<h2>` element.

`<h2>` css:

```
line-height: 22px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
font-size: 16px;
height: 55px;
font-weight: 600;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
```

The `<a>`-element css:

```
color: #333;
    -webkit-transition: color .5s;
    -moz-transition: color .5s;
    -ms-transition: color .5s;
    -o-transition: color .5s;
    transition: color .5s;
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: are you using bootstrap classes?

Comment: show us your html code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39678610/3597276

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing your code in context with the rest of the html and css, I would put `justify-content: center ;` on the parent element ie the h2. I am assuming this is set to be 100% of width to match the width of the image.

Check this out for full info on flex:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 3):

`display: flex` defines an element as a flex container and enables flex properties on all of its **direct** children. Instead of applying flex to `<h2>`, you need to apply it to the parent container for it to work.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <h2>
    <a>Game Title</a>
  </h2>
</div>
```